# How can I make a new, empty hash reference in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, reference

Say I had something like:

```
# %superhash is some predefined hash with more than 0 keys;
%hash = ();
foreach my $key (keys %superhash){
    $superhash{ $key } = %hash;
    %hash = ();
}
```

Would all the keys of superhash point to the same empty hash accessed by `%hash` or would they be different empty hashes?

If not, how can I make sure they point to empty hashes?

Comment: `$hash = {};`; see "perlref(1)".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use the `\` operator to take a reference to a plural data type (array or hash) before you can store it into a single slot of either. But in the example code given, if referenced, each would be the same hash.

The way to initialize your data structure is:

```
foreach my $key (keys %superhash) {
    $superhash{ $key } = {}; # New empty hash reference
}
```

But initialization like this is largely unnecessary in [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) due to autovivification (creating appropriate container objects when a variable is used as a container).

```
my %hash;

$hash{a}{b} = 1;
```

Now `%hash` has one key, 'a', which has a value of an anonymous hashref, containing the key/value pair `b => 1`. Arrays autovivify in the same manner.

Comment: Agreed. No need to carry an extra hash around 
when Perl doesn't need it.

Comment: How would I access the keys of $hash{a}?  When I try `foreach my $rk (keys $hash{a}){...` it gives me an error: the type must be hash

Comment: Ah I got it: `$deref = $hash{a}` and then `foreach $key (keys %$deref){...`

Comment: @Mechko - no need for that, just: `foreach my $key (keys %{$hash{$a}}) { ...`

Comment: @plusplus Ah.  It's curlies.  I kept trying with parentheses.  It didn't work very well :(

Comment: @Mechko => you should read through perlref, perllol and perldsc on perldoc.perl.org, which contain a good overview of how perl's references work, and how to use them to create complex data structures

Comment: Thanks.  I only started perl at 2am yesterday.  So far it's all been instinct.